# SharePoint find list/document URL from search result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a document, let say xyz.doc. When I type xyz.doc in the search, the search result shows the xyz.doc. but how do I find the URL for the list/document library that this xyz.doc is in.

Comment: Right click the link and copy shortcut for the file url and hover and click View Library for the list/library url

Comment: Mr. Ransher Singh, what if the item is not searchable, but you just have the item name. How would one find the list/document library that it is in?

Comment: What you are asking is how to find if an item exists in Sharepoint Content DB and if so, what is the location? I don't know a good way other than run a complete Sharepoint content db inventory using powershell and then checking that result (script similar to what we use for precheck before migrations)